# How pass URL from API to Action (ReactJS)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Get API file

```
import { apiUrl } from '../config'
const baseUri = apiUrl
const uri = {
outline : '/course/income/outline'
 }
const getURI = (key) => baseUri + uri[key]

module.exports = { apiMiddleware, get, post, put, ...{ delete: del }, uri, getURI }
```

Try pass this to my axios URL

```
import Api from '../middleware/api'
    export function IncomeList () {

        return dispatch => {

            return (

                axios.post(Api.getURI(outline),{}, {
          headers: { 'X-Authenticated-Userid': '15000500000@1' }
         }).then(function (response) {


                    console.log(response.data);
                    dispatch(receiveData(response.data.body));

                })
            .catch((error) => {
                    console.log(error);
                })
                )
        }
    }
```

But I get error Uncaught ReferenceError: outline is not defined. How to Pass correct URL ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass string literal to `getURI` method:

```
Api.getURI('outline')
```

Calling `Api.getURI(outline)` makes interpreter look for `outline` variable, which is undefined in the current scope (hence ReferenceError).

Protip: linter, like [ESLint](http://eslint.orgs), would catch this error early.